# Get list of queries and procedures executed in SQL Server instance/database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I get a list of what is being happening on an SQL Server 2008 instance?

I would like to know which queries and procedures have been executed.
A plus would be to know how much time they have spent.

This activity list must be independent from "who" or "what" triggered it. It can be from several applications and several users.

Thanks!

Comment: Turn on auditing on the database.  Check out the Microsoft help pages for this functionality.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like it. I've found some nice resources about it:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90361/Auditing-events-on-SQL-Server-2008 and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166264/Audits-on-MS-SQL-Server-2008

Comment: I'm glad this helped.  I responded from my iPhone.  It's a pain to look things up on a mobile device.

Comment: Does `EXEC sp_who2` not show you what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an older post, but I just found it. If the Audit did what you wanted so far so fine. But did you tried the **SQL Profiler**? Because that is definietly for this reason: checkig exactly what is happening on the SQL Server instance. And you can save the results into a table for further analyzis. (You can even combine it with a result from the Windows Performance Monitor and then you can check what happened on the server during that time)

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1

```
SELECT ObjectName,       
ObjectID,       
DatabaseName,       
StartTime,       
EventClass,       
EventSubClass,       
ObjectType,       
ServerName,       
LoginName,       
NTUserName,       
ApplicationName  
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable( 'Trace File Path', default )            
where EventClass in (46,47,164) and EventSubclass = 0  and DatabaseID = db_id();
```

### How will you get the Trace file Path?

```
SELECT Path FROM sys.traces where is_default = 1 ;
```

### Option #2

### **[This approach will tell which column was added, or what command was used to add](http://sqlandme.com/tag/schema-changes/)**